# Plugin CKEditor outputs something with nothing?

Tags: craft3, plugins, ckeditor5

I have a problem with the CkEditor for Craft CMS.
If I leave the textfield empty and save it, the output in the browser will still contain `<p>&nbsp;</p>` when I want it to be blank. I am thinking about to filtering out with javascript, but I hope someone has a better idea about what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in the master branch, but not yet tagged in a release: https://github.com/craftcms/ckeditor/pull/6

Until it's tagged, you won't be able to get that fix in from the Plugin Store, but you can pull it in with Composer in the command line if you want.

FWIW, it's currently a pretty minimal beta version of the plugin using an older dev preview version of CKEditor 5, so I wouldn't rely on it too heavily until it gets updated.